# Editing a Django view already rendered

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I am currently building a django app that runs a simulation of the dc metro with a google map GUI, similar to the google map at http://www.wmata.com/rail/maps/map.cfm. My desired result is to show the trains running for each line and when a train gets to a station, a point will popup on the map where the station is located and when clicked will give details on the train at the station, passengers, etc. However I run into the problem of how do I show this simulation running on the map once the map has been rendered? Is there a way to update the map after the django view has already been rendered, or is it just not possible? (I'm using the django-gmapi library for the google map)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write client side javascript to (1) get the data for arrivals, and (2) manipulate the map to add/move points. The google maps javascript library is quite friendly and easy to use.